# Looking for a regular expression or an alternate way to specify some syntax

Tags: regex

In a text format, I want to document as a grammar, I have a fixed size string syntax (for the hardcore cases where anything can be inside that string), looking like for example like this:

`#S(5,Hello)`

Is there a way to capture the number 5 and use it subsequently in the same regular expression as a range length specification?

Here the pseudo regular expression I want to get - only I don't know if that is even possible:

`#S(\d AS x,.{x})`

Ideas? If you have an alternative to regular expressions which can do that, I am all ears, too!

Comment: Regular expressions alone cannot do this. You need to write a parser yourself in your favorite programming language

Comment: That's not something regex can do. You should do this in two phases. Check the syntax with regex first (without checking the number of repeats), then check the semantics.

Comment: I know how to implement this - and usually I do not use regular expressions at all. What I am looking for is a concise way to document the syntax. It appears, regular expressions are out of their depths for this.

Comment: found the solution to my documentation problem: instead of giving a grammar, give a concise way how to create the syntax: ``the reverse of printf("#S(%lu,%s)", strlen(s),s)`` ;)